# Cakephp search feature doesn't show the desired items

Tags: php, search, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP, but I'm starting to get into it. I've been having some problems with adding a search feature on my project. I've tried to add with with the instructions of various youtube tutorials and been trying to modify them to work in my project but nothing seems to work. I appreciate the help already!

So here's my Controller code:

```
class ProductsController extends AppController {

public function index() {
   /* $keyword = $this->request->query('keyword');
        if(!empty($keyword)){
        $this-set('products', $this->Product->find()); 
        }     */
    $keyword = $this->request->data('keyword');
    if($keyword != null) 
    {
        $this->set('products', $this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' => '%'.$keyword.'%')));
    }
    else {
        $this->set('products', $this->Product->find('all'));
    }   


}
```

And here is my index file (main page):

```html
    <div id="listaus">
    <?= $this->Html->link('+ Listaa Uusi Auto', ['action' => 'add']) ?>
    
    <?= $this->Form->create("", array('type' => 'get')); ?>   
        <?= $this->Form->control('keyword'); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end(__('Search')); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <?php foreach ($products as $product):?>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="">
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($product['Product']['kuva']),
     array('action'=>'view',$product['Product']['id']),
     array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'thumbnail'));?>
   <div class="caption">
    <h4>
     <?php echo $product['Product']['name'];?>
    </h4>
    <h5>
     Price:
     <?php echo $product['Product']['hinta'];?>
                     &euro;
    </h5>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Hopefully someone has a solution for my problem, thanks! :)

Comment: Use [Search](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) as it offers proper filtering for these kind of scenarios, using standard PRG pattern etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't add LIKE clause to match the search condition.

Try to change

```
$this->set('products', $this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' => '%'.$keyword.'%')));
```

**to**

```
 $this->set('products', 
      $this->Product->find('all', 
        array(
         'conditions' => 
            array(
                   'Product.name LIKE ' => '%'.$keyword.'%'
            )
        )
      )
    );
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It doesn't give any error, it gets the keyword but can't use it correctly. EDIT: It worked when I used $this->request->query instead of $this->request->data

Comment: Great. $this->request->query is used to access query string and $this->request->data is used to get posted data.